can’t access custom field in the meta json
i have a custom post type book, and in its args i have
'show_in_rest'  => true,

now i want to add a custom field to it like so:
add_action( 'init', 'add_to_rest_test' );

function add_to_rest_test(){
   $meta_args = array(
     'type'         => 'string',
     'description'  => 'A meta key associated with a string meta value.',
     'single'       => true,
     'show_in_rest' => true,
  );
 register_post_meta( 'book', 'testing_field', $meta_args );
}

but then when i go to the post json: myexamplesite/wp-json/wp/v2/book…. there is no “meta” section. But if i change the code to regular post:
register_post_meta( 'post', 'testing_field', $meta_args );

in the json i do have a meta section:
"meta": {
"testing_field": "",
"footnotes": ""
},

what am i missing here? appriciate any help

When registering book, you need to add 'supports' => ['custom-fields']:
register_post_type( 'book', [
...
'supports' => [ 'title', 'editor', 'custom-fields', ... ],
...
] );


thank you. i can't beleave i missed that.
